# Help with LWC, trigger and flow

Tags: trigger, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

in the work, have a task and i need some help with a combination of salesforce elements.

**I need to create a flow that is executed before saving an element and check the empty fields. If the object have empty fields, appears a pop up LWC component which works as a warning notifying of empty specific fields**

This is possible? is it feasible to use lwc for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're looking for [this Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdin5UAB/warning-messages)? Unfortunately, you can't produce any kind of UI in the middle of a DML operation. Your only real choice at this point is to generate error(s), which the user would then have to fix, or create a custom edit page in Aura/LWC, so you can handle such problems before submitting the DML operation. Note that any solution of this nature won't work for API-based DML operations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will wait if someone else appears with another answer, if not I mark yours as the one that solves the problem